# Sql server select condition case when

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use `IF` condition and i got to long script.

So I want to use `CASE` `WHEN` to make script shorter.

How to change scipt below to use `CASE` `WHEN` instead of `IF`:

```
DECLARE @SDATE1 DATE='2015-01-01'
DECLARE @EDATE1 DATE='2016-01-01'
DECLARE @ASOF VARCHAR(10)='YES'

IF @ASOF='YES' 

select * from customer 

ELSE 

select * from customer WHERE
CAST(CUSTDATE AS DATE)END 
BETWEEN @SDATE1 AND @EDATE1
```

Comment: No - just no. Firstly, trying to minimize coding work is just laziness - which is evidenced by the use of asterisk as column list. The approach you have chosen might just lead to performance problems - and you already have a potential performance problem by casting a column to date in your where clause. How to search by date is [here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well how about just write more complex condition

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer WHERE
(@ASOF != 'YES'
   AND CAST(CUSTDATE AS DATE) BETWEEN @SDATE1 AND @EDATE1)
OR @ASOF = 'YES'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @SDATE1 DATE='2015-01-01'
DECLARE @EDATE1 DATE='2016-01-01'
DECLARE @ASOF VARCHAR(10)='YES'

SELECT  * 
FROM    customer 
WHERE   (CAST(CUSTDATE AS DATE) >= @SDATE1 AND CAST(CUSTDATE AS DATE) <= @EDATE1 AND @ASOF <> 'YES')
    OR  @ASOF='YES'
```

I've also removed the syntactically incorrect `END`, and replaced the `between` with `>=  <=`. See [here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) for some potential problems with `between`.